# Discover: An error occurred with your request. Reset your inputs and try again from Kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

Anyone experiencing this problem. My elasticsearch version is 1.4.5.

[image: Discover Error]

Thank you and please assist

Comment: Which exact version of Kibana do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already solve this problem by updating java, elasticsearch, logstash and kibana.

Thank you